# How can `iframe` event listener detect `escape` key event?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a `iframe` embedded in my dom. And I use below code to make it focus:

```
$("#my-iframe")[0].contentWindow.focus()
```

Below is the event listener inside iframe:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) { 
  console.log(" this is from iframe event:", event);

});
```

I can see the console log for other key press but `escape`. Is there anything special for `escape` key?

Comment: That event listener should work just fine for Esc. Can you post a [mcve] we can copy-and-paste and run locally to see the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by change `document.addEventListener` to `window.addEventListener`. I am not sure what the different between `document` and `window` here.

Comment: Didn't work for me, assuming we're trying to achieve the same thing: which is to detect ESC press, when iframe on a page is in focus (i.e. clicked by mouse).

Answer (score 0):

This was the only thing that worked for me. It uses the `document` of the `iframe` instead of the document of the page.

```js
let iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
let doc = iframe.contentDocument;

doc.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an idea why document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument works but $('#iframe').contentDocument does not? Imagine there are multiple iframes on the page.

Comment: The .contentDocument is not a standard jQuery method; instead, you should use jQuery to select the iframe and then access its content document through the get(0) method or the [0] index `var iframe = $('#iframe')[0]; // Using [0] or .get(0) to access the first iframe
var contentDocument = iframe.contentDocument;`